# Angular (Material) - dialog close - which button was pressed

Tags: dialog, angular5

I use this code in my Angular 5 application:

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DatechoiceCreationDateDialogComponent, {
  data: data
});    

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
    this.fetchEvents(); // events are fetched also if close button is pressed
 })
```

Can I differentiate somehow if the close button is pressed because therefore I don't need to reload/fetch events?